# Can't remove runtime generated control in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I can't seem to remove a button which will have been generated during runtime.

Here's the code that generates the button:

```
void testArea(Object s, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.Button myButton = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
        myButton.Name = "runtimeGeneratedButton";
        myButton.Content = "deleteMe";
        myButton.Click+= new RoutedEventHandler(deleter);
        operationsPannel.Children.Add(myButton);
    }
```

And here's the code that is supposed to remove the generated button:

```
private void deleter(object s, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        operationsPannel.Children.Remove(operationsPannel.FindName("runtimeGeneratedButton") as System.Windows.Controls.Button);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For controls that you create in code, if you want to find them by name, you need to [`RegisterName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.registername.aspx) in current name scope:

```
operationsPannel.Children.Add(myButton);
operationsPannel.RegisterName("runtimeGeneratedButton", myButton);
```

this is done automatically by XAML parser